# Pointer Address gives a 1 instead of hexadecimal adress

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, sdl

I'm trying to make it so I have one object, that has a pointer, so multiple classes can work with the same object. But the only thing it's giving me is 1 instead of the hexadecimal address that I need.
My code:

code to create it:

```
SDL_Event event;
EventHandler eh(&event);
```

code using it:

```
EventHandler::EventHandler(SDL_Event* eventpointer)
{
    EventHandler::event = eventpointer;
    //This code is to test the pointer:
    std::cout << &EventHandler::event << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
1
Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 0.092 s
```

Answer (score 3):

Try printing the *value* of event, not the address of it:

```
std::cout << EventHandler::event << std::endl;
```

There are actually several unusual things about your testcase. Correcting all of them, I end up with this:

```
EventHandler::EventHandler(SDL_Event* eventpointer) : event(eventpointer)
{
  //This code is to test the pointer:
  std::cout << event << "\n";
}
```

The things I changed are:

- Prefer initialization lists to assigning values in constructor bodies
- Print value of `event` variable not its address. The value of `event` is the same as the value of `eventpointer`, which is the same as the *address* of the original `SDL_Event` object.
- Avoid the scope qualifier. Inside the class's functions, you may refer to members simply by name.

---

*Aside*: I'm going to answer the actual question in an aside since it turns out to be irrelevant to the author's true intent. The actual reason he sees `1` instead of a pointer value is this: he is trying to print the value of a pointer-to-member. `operator<<` has no overload which takes a pointer-to-member, so it converts it to `bool` instead. His expression is non-null, so the conversion results in `true`, which is printed as 1.